# Textbox values lost after back button on Firefox

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have a web page, clicking a button it updates a textbox T1 on the page (locally via jquery) and then aspnet server gets the submit, makes a Csharp process and open another href (response.redirect)  on the same page.

The problem is that, going back with browser back button, IE and Chrome give you T1 with the same values written before,  while Firefox gives ALWAYS T1 empty.
Cannot understand why.

Has anybody ever encountered this. I have isolated all the process, so the button writes the textbox and calls the other page, no postback, no aspnet. An alert after the update T1 -reads- again T1 to verify it is written. But after BACK button it's again empty.

Thanks....Sav